# SQL - Update a field with part of a string from another field

Tags: sql-server, string, date, datetime, sql-update

I'm unsure if this can be done with anything other than regex or some other fancy solution, but here's what I need to do.

Column A: standard SQL datetime value

Column B: varchar field with values that I need to extract data from

A typical Column B value would look like:
**Here are some comments about this document Create Date: 2011-08-17T20:10:33Z Modify Date: 2011-06-22T17:54:23Z**

The create date/modify date were sourced from another system and inserted in this field for review by end users.

What I would like to do is pull out the Create Date value and update Column A to match. I realize I would need to do some date-time format converting, but how difficult would this script actually be? I can't figure out a way to just pull **Create Date: 2011-08-17T20:10:33Z** from that string and use that as a value to update column A. If converting that date value proves too difficult, it would be acceptable to just use the date portion of this, such as '2011-08-17'

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said what you have tried so far! Here is a tip to get you started.. 

DECLARE @x varchar(100) = 'blah blah Create Date: 2011-08-17T20:10:33Z Modify Date: 2011-06-22T17:54:23Z';

SELECT 
@x original_data
, CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x))) FirstIndexOfdate
  ,CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)), (CHARINDEX('-', LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)) )+1)) SecondIndexOfdate
GO



See where I am going with this??

Comment: Thanks  for this. The main reason I hadn't posted anything is that I am not good with regex. So if regex is the only way, then I will need to find help on properly doing this. Do you think this is the only option?

Comment: Not at all.. the code I have above will give you the location of the first date: and second date: inside the column.. you should be able to extract the value based on that. Give it a go and see if you can get the value out.. else can provide more help.. it's probably better this way than to give you the exact answer in code.

Comment: Try and see if this works----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @x varchar(100) = 'blah blah Create Date: 2011-08-17T20:10:33Z Modify Date: 2011-06-22T17:54:23Z'; 
SELECT @x original_data
 , CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x))) FirstIndexOfdate 
,CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)), (CHARINDEX('Date:', LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)) )+1)) SecondIndexOfdate 
,substring (@x,CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)))+5,11) first_date
,substring (@x,CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)), (CHARINDEX('Date:', LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)) )+1)) +5,11) second_date

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me get started here on this! Very much appreciated for the tips. Will be spending time tomorrow tinkering with this to get results. You rock!

Comment: sweet.. I'll put that in as an answer and can you accept that as an answer if that works for you thanks

Comment: How about accepting the answer below if it did the trick for you?

Comment: I definitely will be with my findings, I have not forgotten. I had a number of related issues come up while testing that made this go longer. I truly am appreciative of this, and I will be posting results very soon. Standby.

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this works.. basically this finds the first Date and gets the value from there and then the second date and the value following that.. this assumes that all your entries follow the same format as you have specified.

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100) = 'blah blah Create Date: 2011-08-17T20:10:33Z Modify Date: 2011-06-22T17:54:23Z';

SELECT @x original_data 

, CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x))) FirstIndexOfdate 

,CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)), (CHARINDEX('Date:', LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)) )+1)) SecondIndexOfdate 

,substring (@x,CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)))+5,11) first_date 

,substring (@x,CHARINDEX('Date:',LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)), (CHARINDEX('Date:', LTRIM(RTRIM(@x)) )+1)) +5,11)
```